# Google Analytics in CakePHP blog

Tags: cakephp, blogs

My webmaster is on vacation and I need a way to add Google Analytics code on my blog. I've looked everywhere and couldn't find the header file where to place code.

I don't have the site on a live server yet but here's an example of the blog path.

example.com/blogs/blog

I have a "Blogs" folder located at `/public_html/app/views/blogs` but all the files in there don't have the tags  where I can place GA code. Is there somewhere else I need to look for and index file?

I put code in `/public_html/app/views/layouts/index.ctp`, it's only showing on the main site page but not the blog.

Please help - thanks

Comment: Wait for your webmaster to return. :) It sounds you're likely to break your blog.

Comment: Couldn't wait ;-) but I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP headers and footers are together in a layout file.
The default layout file is `views/layouts/default.ctp`.

Comment: Thanks,  I have indexlayout.ctp, but when I put GA code in header, tracking code only show in example.com not example.com/blogs/blog

Comment: I don't know what layouts your blog is using. Maybe you have several layouts for different pages.

Comment: Thanks I found it in the layout folder under a different weird name.